# Node how to manipulate HTML DOM - document not found error

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a Node server that serves various different HTML pages. In one of the pages there is a form.  When the form is clicked, an endpoint in the node server.js file consumes the form data.  The same HTML page contains a

element whose text content i'd like to modify when the form is submitted. I've seen various tutorials online showcasing how to use `document.getElementById('predictionText').innerHTML = prediction;` to set the value of the text dynamically using inline javascript.  How do I achieve this using Node and external js?

Below is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>

  <body class="bodyContent">
    <p>This is the predictor page -- it will hold a form for the user to input relevant data to.</p>
    <section class="active" id="navigationBarSection">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="predictor">Predictor</a></li>
        <li><a href="how_it_works">How it Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="about_us">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>

    <section id="predictorUserInputSection">
    <form action="/post_data_to_predictor_algorithm" method="POST" id="attributeInputForm">
      <input class="textInput" required name="averageAreaIncome" placeholder="Average Area Income" />
      <input class="textInput" required name="averageAreaNumberOfRooms" placeholder="Average Area Number of Rooms" />
      <input class="textInput" required name="averageAreaHouseAge" placeholder="Average Area House Age" />
      <input class="textInput" required name="averageAreaNumberOfBedrooms" placeholder="Average Area Number of Bedrooms"/>
      <input class="textInput" required name="areaPopulation" placeholder="Area Population"/>
      <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </section>

  <section id="predictionResultsSection">
    <p id="predictionText"><font size="6">here </p>
  </section>

  <script src="server.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

The node server that should update the text:

```js
//jshint esversion:8

//adding all required dependencies/packages
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //for parsing post requests
const request = require('request') //for making HTTP requests

//specifies that this app will be using express.
const app = express();

//middleware for processing POST requests a bit easier.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

//static AWS EC2 instance server port. Edit with caution.
const serverPort = 5001;

const FLASK_SERVER_LOCAL_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000/predictPrice";

//Allow the use of static files in project directory
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/html', express.static(__dirname + '/html'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use('/resources', express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));

const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;


//Handle all root requests.
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("index.html"));
});

app.get("/index", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("index.html"));
});

app.get("/predictor", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("html/predictor.html"));
});

app.get("/how_it_works", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("html/how_it_works.html"));
});

app.get("/about_us", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve("html/about_us.html"))
});


//HERE IS THE PROBLEM
app.post("/post_data_to_predictor_algorithm", (req, res) => {
  //update prediction label in the UI:
  console.log("Updating label!");
  document.getElementById('predictionText').innerHTML = "received user response!";
});
```

When running the server, I get the following error when submitting the form:

```sh
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at app.post (/Users/vismarkjuarez/Documents/Github/RealEstatePriceEstimator/server.js:90:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/vismarkjuarez/Documents/Github/RealEstatePriceEstimator/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/vismarkjuarez/Documents/Github/RealEstatePriceEstimator/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/vismarkjuarez/Documents/Github/RealEstatePriceEstimator/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/vismarkjuarez/Documents/Github/RealEstatePriceEstimator/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/vismarkjuarez/Documents/Github/RealEstatePriceEstimator/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/vismarkjuarez/Documents/Github/RealEstatePriceEstimator/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/vismarkjuarez/Documents/Github/RealEstatePriceEstimator/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/vismarkjuarez/Documents/Github/RealEstatePriceEstimator/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
    at invokeCallback (/Users/vismarkjuarez/Documents/Github/RealEstatePriceEstimator/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want update DOM element in the same page of form, you have to build a dynamic form cause the standard one with action="/destination" will send you to a new page, or rebuild an existing one where you cant write on the document cause node dont know DOM. You need Jquery or work directly with xhr. For instance:

```
// Build a single field dynamic Form:

<div id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="textA"></input>
  <button type="submit" onclick="getElements()"> Submit </button>
</div>


// The element that need be updated.

<section id="predictionResultsSection">
   <p id="predictionText"><font size="6">here </p>
</section>


// Get the "form" field value.

function getElements() {
    var tA = document.getElementById("textA");
    formSubmit(tA.value)
}


// Do the request 

function formSubmit(sendData) {

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/post_data_to_predictor_algorithm");
  xhttp.send(sendData);

  // Receive the response from server on this.responseText var
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    document.getElementById('predictionText').innerHTML = this.responseText;

    }
  };

}


// Server side
app.post("/post_data_to_predictor_algorithm", (req, res) => {
  //do your logic and send the response

  res.send(yourResponse) // the onreadystatechange will hadle this on responseText

});
```